# MS SQL Как вывести полученную сумму за месяц?

Tags: sql-server

Написал запрос который в теории должен выводить сумму которая доставка заработала за месяц(5) ->

```
SELECT SUM(Products.Price * OrdersProducts.Quantity) AS 'SUM'
FROM Products, OrdersProducts
WHERE MONTH(Orders.Date_Order) = 5 AND YEAR(Orders.Date_Order) = YEAR(getdate())
```

Только на практике не работает потому что не как не связал Orders.Date_Order, можете пожалуйста подсказать как можно связаться с Orders.Date_Order

Comment: наверняка в orders есть id_product, нужен join между таблицами по этому полю

Comment: Подозреваю, что вам еще нужно GROUP BY по продуктам сделать, иначе это будет сумма всего и вся. Могу ошибаться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А как вы учитываете изменение цен со временем? Цена бы по идее должна либо с заказом вместе храниться, либо должна быть таблица истории цен.
Если у вас в заказах есть индекс по дате, то накладывая функции поля даты индекс использовать не будет.
В целом ваш запрос должен быть каким-то таким:

```
SELECT SUM(p.price * op.quantity) AS sum
FROM OrdersProduct AS op
INNER JOIN Products AS p ON (
    p.id = op.product_id
)
WHERE op.date_order BETWEEN '2023-05-01' AND '2023-05-31'
```

В общем для использования индекса (при  наличии, конечно) манипуляции с датами надо на параметры перенести, а не на поле таблицы.
И если дата это все же дата-время, то конец интервала это `2023-05-31 23:59:59`. Либо как вариант - вместо `between` можно использовать неравенства и собрать дату:

```
WHERE op.date_order >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), 5, 1)
    AND op.date_order < DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), 6, 1)
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, не много изменил под свой вариант - SELECT SUM(p.Price * op.Quantity) AS 'Sum'
FROM Products AS p
INNER JOIN OrdersProducts  AS op ON (
    op.Product_ID = p.Product_ID
)
INNER JOIN Orders AS o ON (
    o.Order_ID = op.Order_ID
)
WHERE o.date_order >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), 5, 1) AND o.date_order < DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), 6, 1)